# Find the probability $P[ x(t) \le 1]$ where $x(t)$ is a filtered Poisson process (rect pulses)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random

I can't understand the following question:

"The random process x(t) is defined as $$x(t) = \sum_{n=- \infty}^{+\infty} rect(\frac{t-\tau_{n}}{T}) \quad ,\quad t \ \epsilon \ (R)$$ where {$\tau_{n}$} are the ordered arrival times of a homogeneous Poisson process with rate $\lambda = \frac{0.8}{T}$.

Find the probability $P[x(t) \le 1]$."

I can't understand the question. The process $x(t)$ should be a filtered Poisson process, but how can I say that the $\mathbf sum$ of the random rect signals is equal to a certain value??

Thanks in advance, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each $x(t)$ depends on the random sequence $(\tau_n)$ hence $x(t)$ is random. For example, the event $[x(t)=0]$ corresponds to every rectangular function in the series evaluating to $0$, that is, to the event that $|t-\tau_n|\gt\frac12T$ for every $n$. Considering the random set $\mathfrak T=\{\tau_n\mid n\in\mathbb Z\}$, one gets $$[x(t)=0]=[\mathfrak T\cap[t-\tfrac12T,t+\tfrac12T]=\varnothing],
$$
from which $P(x(t)=0)$ can be deduced since the size of the random set $\mathfrak T\cap[t-\tfrac12T,t+\tfrac12T]$ is a Poisson random variable with known parameter. Can you do the same for the event $[x(t)\leqslant1]$?

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.
Well, if I understand, the size of the random set is the increment of our Poisson process $N_{x}(t-\frac{1}{2}T \ , \ t+\frac{1}{2}T)$ so the probability of the event $[x(t) \le 1]$ should be: $$P[N_{x}(t-\frac{1}{2}T \ , \ t+\frac{1}{2}T)=1] = \sum_{k=0}^{1}e^{-\lambda T}\frac{(\lambda T)^k}{k!}$$

correct?

Comment: Sorry I meant $$P[N_{x}(t-\frac{1}{2}T \ , \ t+\frac{1}{2}T) \le 1] = \sum_{k=0}^{1}e^{-\lambda T}\frac{(\lambda T)^k}{k!}$$

Comment: That is, $\mathrm e^{-0.8}(1+0.8)$.

Comment: Thank you very much, your hint was priceless!!